# find and delete special characters in TCL

Tags: linux, tcl

I have special characters :

```
abc[1]
```

I want find pattern `[:number:]` And i want it to become

```
abc_1_
```

How to find pattern `[:number:]`
i try to use `string match "*[*" $list`. but it is not active

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `string match` command isn't really the right tool for the job. It doesn't tell you *where* it matched things, and `[` is a metacharacter in its little match language (used for introducing a restricted form of `*`).

In your case, you're far better off using `regsub`:

```
regsub {\[(\d+)\]} $inputString {_\1_}
```

For example:

```
puts [regsub {\[(\d+)\]} {abc[1]} {_\1_}]
```

The RE itself is this: `\[(\d+)\]`. That's a literal `[` (backslash-quoted because it is an RE metacharacter), a captured subsequence of one or more digits, and a literal `]` (with backslash quote). The substitution replacement is `_\1_`, a pair of `_` characters with the first (and only) captured subsequence between them.

You *might* need the `-all` option to `regsub` if there's many replacements to do in a string at once.

---

If you're looking to get rid of problem characters in general, `regsub` is the right approach. However, it can take some fiddling to get the right RE. With some simplifications though…

```
puts [regsub -all {\W+} {abc[1]} "_"]
```

That one doesn't actually do what you asked for… but it does more like what many people want when they ask questions in this area as it changes *all* sequences of non-alphanumeric characters into single underscores (modulo a little weirdness with `_` itself).

Comment: if input is any number, what should i do?
example : abc[2] abc[3]. 
my purpose is to change " [ " and "]" into " undercore"

Comment: `\d+` means "one or more digits", so Donal's answer will work for you.

Comment: i mean "{_\1_}"